# The timer works fine if it's coded inside a button_click event handler, but it doesn't work if it is inside a method

Tags: c#

I found timer code from a web site and used it in my application and it works fine if I use the timer code inside a button_click handler, but I need to use the timer when I call a method, so I did copy and paste the same code from the button_click into the method but the timer always gives me zero. How do I fix it?

The following is the timer code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Timer decleration
    DateTime startTime, StopTime;
    TimeSpan stoppedTime;
    bool reset;

    bool startVariabl = true;
    // The rest of the code..

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (startVariable) startMethod();
        //
        //The rest of the code...
    }

    private void startMethod()
    {
        //Timer
        tmDisplay.Enabled = true;

        // Reset display to zero
        reset = true;
        lblElapsed.Text = "00:00.00.0";

        // Start timer and get starting time
        if (reset)
        {
            reset = false;
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            stoppedTime = new TimeSpan(0);
        }
        else
        {
            stoppedTime += DateTime.Now - StopTime;
        }
    }

    private void tmDisplay_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime currentTime;

        //Determine Ellapsed Time
        currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Display Time
        lblElapsed.Text = HMS(currentTime - startTime - stoppedTime);
    }

    private string HMS(TimeSpan tms)
    {
        //Format time as string; leaving off last six decimal places.
        string s = tms.ToString();
        return (s.Substring(0, s.Length - 6));
    }
```

I am new C# learner.

Comment: Have you attached `tmDisplay_Tick` to the `Tick` event of the timer? I assume `tmDisplay` is your timer, so wherever you've declared it, make sure you've got `tmDisplay.Tick += new EventHandler(tmDisplay_Tick);` and set its `Interval` property.

Comment: I don't see the timer declaration or where you're doing anything with it aside from enabling it.

Comment: I think what you really want is a `Stopwatch` rather than a `Timer`. Or perhaps you want a `Stopwatch` to keep track of the amount of time elapsed and a `Timer` to periodically show it. But the code you show here is either incomplete or it has a bug. `stoppedTime` is never updated because the `else` portion of your `startMethod` is never executed.

Comment: Yes Jim Mischel i use it as a stopwatch, and I use the stoppedTime in different pace when I need to stop the stopWatch or I call it timer.

Comment: keyboardP, where did you mean add this code: tmDisplay.Tick += new EventHandler(tmDisplay_Tick); the interval is set to default value whch is 100

Comment: @BASIM HAFIDH - You can add it wherever you've intialised the Timer. Or, you can add in the `startMethod`, just before `tmDisplay.Enabled = true;`. If you want to create a stopwatch, then you don't need to do all this manually. You can use the `StopWatch` class as Jim Mischel mentioned:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: Thank you KeyboardP, I will read about Stopwatch class and try to use it in my program. Thanks again keyboardP and thanks Jim Mischel for your help.

Comment: hey guys, what's up with giving answers in comments? you are too shy to write proper answer or is there some SO policy update memo I missed?

Answer (score 0):

as keyboardP suggested in a comment you should add this line:

```
tmDisplay.Tick += new EventHandler(tmDisplay_Tick);
```

usually Tick handler is set once (unless you need to switch it to other callback or nullify it for some reason) so I would add it in your Form constructor assuming that timer is already created then or after timer initialization if you do it in some method.